# How to repeat a click handler in ngRepeat (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following problem. I wanna repeat menu links. But the program doesn't create the corresponding click handler.

View:

```
//view is created by Angular Material
<md-menu-item ng-repeat="mItem in ::menuItems">
    <md-button ng-click="mItem[action]">
        <md-icon>{{ ::mItem.icon }}</md-icon>
        {{ ::mItem.name }}
    </md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Ctrl:

```
$scope.menuItems = [
        { icon: 'mode_edit', name: 'Edit', action: 'clickEdit()' },
        { icon: 'delete', name: 'Delete', action: 'clickDelete()' }
    ];

$scope.clickEdit = clickEdit;
$scope.clickDelete = clickDelete;

    function clickEdit() {
        $log.info('edit clicked');
    }

    function clickDelete() {
        //code...
    }
```

What I need to do to get the handlers in ngClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to keep that logic in a service like this:

```
//view is created by Angular Material
<md-menu-item ng-repeat="mItem in ::menuItems">
    <md-button ng-click="action(mItem.action)">
        <md-icon>{{ ::mItem.icon }}</md-icon>
        {{ ::mItem.name }}
    </md-button>
</md-menu-item>

$scope.menuItems = [
    { icon: 'mode_edit', name: 'Edit', action: 'edit' },
    { icon: 'delete', name: 'Delete', action: 'delete' }
];

$scope.action = function(actionName){
   // call service
}
```

Comment: It is a good solution I will try it :) and give you a feedback.